# best method to set rownames or row.names?

Tags: r

Is there any difference between this 3 methods to set row names?

```
x1 <- data.frame(1)          ## I think this one is faster.why?
attr(x1,"row.names") <- 10L

x2 <- data.frame(1)
row.names(x2) <- 10L

x3 <- data.frame(1)
rownames(x3) <- 10L
```

Comment: `row.names<-.data.frame` checks for uniqueness, and `rownames<-` is equivalent to the former in the case of a `data.frame`.

Answer (score 2):

(Edited to include Jake Burkhead's solution).

The first one is faster. Don't know why for sure, but presumably because accessing by identifier or by function adds some overhead.

```
x1 <- data.frame(1)
x2 <- data.frame(1)
x3 <- data.frame(1)
x4 <- data.frame(1)

microbenchmark(
  attr(x1, "row.names") <- 10L,
  structure(x2, row.names = 10L),
  row.names(x3) <- 10L,
  rownames(x4) <- 10L)
```

This is the result on my machine:

```
Unit: microseconds
                           expr    min      lq median      uq    max neval
   attr(x1, "row.names") <- 10L  2.625  4.4975  4.795  5.1100  7.257   100
 structure(x2, row.names = 10L) 18.646 25.0555 26.855 27.6205 48.376   100
           row.names(x3) <- 10L 20.517 27.8335 28.795 30.3845 90.025   100
            rownames(x4) <- 10L 22.027 31.0540 31.785 32.9445 55.254   100
```

Comment: This isn't an answer. It just restates what OP already observes.

Comment: Actually it confirms it. Don't expect an accept, but I can't yet post comments.

Comment: `structure(as.data.frame(1), row.names = 10L, names = "X1")` is even faster for me

Comment: @JakeBurkhead can't reproduce, the `structure` way is the slowest for me. Interestingly though, unlike `attr`, it does prevent you from assigning duplicate rownames.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde are you creating the data frames within the benchmark? Just assigning row.names/rownames is gonna be faster but structure also creates the data frame. I guess the question is specifically asking about assigning row.names so creating the data frame shouldnt be benchmarked

Comment: No, but I misread the output. My results agree with @coanil's.

Comment: Is `setattr` from the `data.table` packages faster?

Comment: @Frank it depends. `attr<-` will copy the object if it referenced elsewhere and in that circumstance `setattr` will be a little faster. Otherwise, i.e. if `attr<-` doesn't copy it seems a little slower (I'm guessing this can be improved). To check copying behavior via microbenchmark, add e.g. `y = x1` to each line of the bench, e.g. `{y = x1; attr(x1, 'row.names') <- 10L}`

Comment: I may have screwed up my previous bench, as I'm now getting it to match `attr<-` when `attr<-` doesn't copy, making it faster or same speed in all cases.